# Can't scp from linux ubuntu server to local windows machine

Tags: server, scp

I want to transfer a file from my remote linux ubuntu server to my local windows machine but it give me this error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

here is the command that I enter into my linux server command line

```
scp -r root@MY.LINUX.IP:/var/www/test.py C:/Users/test/Desktop/
```

Comment: shouldn't you be running that command on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your windows machine is local and unreachable from the internet you must run the scp command on your windows machine, not on the remote host. If you are using wsl your C: drive will be available on /mnt/c DOS style paths wont work. Using WinSCP maybe easier in this case.